# XText formatting rule for referenced elements

Tags: formatting, xtext

I'm trying to describe the problem, with a simple example. Lets say, that I have a grammar, that looks like this:

```
Model:
    rules+=Rule*;

Rule:
    View | Element;

Element:
    'element' name=ID members+=Member members+=Member* 'end';

View:
    'view' name=ID 'for' forElement=[Element] 
    forMembers+=[Member] forMembers+=[Member]* 'end';

Member:
    'member' name=ID;
```

A simple example of this language would be:

```
// Element is where the Members are instantiated
element Foo
    member bar
    member foobar
    member barfoo
    member something
end

// Views only reference the members by simple name
view FooView for Foo
    bar 
    foobar 
    something
end
```

I have a custom scope provider for the `forMembers` attribute of the `View rule`:

```
class MyDslScopeProvider extends AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider {
    def scope_View_forMembers(View view, EReference reference) {
        Scopes.scopeFor(view.forElement.members);
    }
}
```

Everything is good so far, **my question comes here:**

I also have a formatter, where I'm unable to add rules for the referenced `Member`s:

```
class MyDslFormatter extends AbstractDeclarativeFormatter {

    @Inject extension MyDslGrammarAccess

    override protected void configureFormatting(FormattingConfig c) {

        // Rules for element: line breaks, indentation increment and decrement
        c.setLinewrap(1).after(elementAccess.nameAssignment_1)
        c.setLinewrap(1).after(elementRule)
        c.setIndentationIncrement.after(elementAccess.nameAssignment_1)
        c.setIndentationDecrement.before(elementAccess.endKeyword_4)

        // Rules for view: line breaks, indentation increment and decrement
        c.setLinewrap(1).after(viewAccess.forElementElementCrossReference_3_0)
        c.setLinewrap(1).after(viewRule)
        c.setIndentationIncrement.after(viewAccess.forElementElementCrossReference_3_0)
        c.setIndentationDecrement.before(viewAccess.endKeyword_6)

        //formatting for Member rule, only works, where Member rules are instantiated.
        c.setLinewrap(1).after(memberRule)
    }
}
```

As you can see, i have set up the formatting for the `Element` and `View` rules, and also for the `Member` rule. However the **formatting for the `Member` rule is only applied, where its instantiated** (e.g.: the `Element` declaration). When i run this formatter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) i get the following format:

```
element Foo
    member bar
    member foobar
    member barfoo
    member something
end
view FooView for Foo
    bar foobar something end
```

However I would like to have all the referenced Members in a new line too. **How can this be achieved?** Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Members are referenced in View rule. You have to set linewrap after these members:

```
    c.setLinewrap(1).after(viewAccess.forMembersAssignment_4)
    c.setLinewrap(1).after(viewAccess.forMembersAssignment_5)
```